# Procedure inside a procedure?

Tags: delphi

I found this code online that has a procedure inside a procedure.
I cannot understand why the author would have chosen to write it this way. 
What I do notice is a recursive function being executed.

Why did he not separate the procedures like most code I have seen.

His implementation:

```
procedure XML2Form(tree : TJvPageListTreeView; XMLDoc : TXMLDocument);
var
  iNode : IXMLNode;

  procedure ProcessNode(
    Node : IXMLNode; 
    tn   : TTreeNode);
  var
    cNode : IXMLNode;
  begin
    if Node = nil then Exit;
    with Node do
    begin
      tn := tree.Items.AddChild(tn, Attributes['text']);
      tn.ImageIndex := Integer(Attributes['imageIndex']);
      tn.StateIndex := Integer(Attributes['stateIndex']);
    end;

    cNode := Node.ChildNodes.First;
    while cNode <> nil do
    begin
      ProcessNode(cNode, tn);
      cNode := cNode.NextSibling;
    end;
  end; (*ProcessNode*) 
begin
  tree.Items.Clear;
  XMLDoc.FileName := ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0),'.XML');
  XMLDoc.Active := True;

  iNode := XMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First;

  while iNode <> nil do
  begin
    ProcessNode(iNode,nil);
    iNode := iNode.NextSibling;
  end;
  XMLDoc.Active := False;
end; (* XML2Form *)


procedure Form2XML(tree: TJVPageListTreeView);
var
  tn : TTreeNode;
  XMLDoc : TXMLDocument;
  iNode : IXMLNode;

  procedure ProcessTreeItem(
    tn    : TTreeNode;
    iNode : IXMLNode);
  var
    cNode : IXMLNode;
  begin
    if (tn = nil) then Exit;
    cNode := iNode.AddChild('item');
    cNode.Attributes['text'] := tn.Text;
    cNode.Attributes['imageIndex'] := tn.ImageIndex;
    cNode.Attributes['stateIndex'] := tn.StateIndex;
    cNode.Attributes['selectedIndex'] := tn.SelectedIndex;

    //child nodes
    tn := tn.getFirstChild;
    while tn <> nil do
    begin
      ProcessTreeItem(tn, cNode);
      tn := tn.getNextSibling;
    end;
  end; (*ProcessTreeItem*)
begin
  XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  XMLDoc.Active := True;
  iNode := XMLDoc.AddChild('tree2xml');
  iNode.Attributes['app'] := ParamStr(0);

  tn := tree.TopItem;
  while tn <> nil do
  begin
    ProcessTreeItem (tn, iNode);

    tn := tn.getNextSibling;
  end;

  XMLDoc.SaveToFile(ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0),'.XML'));
  XMLDoc := nil;
end; (* Form2XML *)
```

or modified implementation:

```
procedure ProcessNode(Node : IXMLNode; tn : TTreeNode);
var
  cNode : IXMLNode;
begin
  if Node = nil then Exit;
  with Node do
  begin
    tn := tree.Items.AddChild(tn, Attributes['text']);
    tn.ImageIndex := Integer(Attributes['imageIndex']);
    tn.StateIndex := Integer(Attributes['stateIndex']);
  end;

  cNode := Node.ChildNodes.First;
  while cNode <> nil do
  begin
    ProcessNode(cNode, tn);
    cNode := cNode.NextSibling;
  end;
end; (*ProcessNode*)

procedure ProcessTreeItem(tn : TTreeNode; iNode : IXMLNode);
var
  cNode : IXMLNode;
begin
  if (tn = nil) then Exit;
  cNode := iNode.AddChild('item');
  cNode.Attributes['text'] := tn.Text;
  cNode.Attributes['imageIndex'] := tn.ImageIndex;
  cNode.Attributes['stateIndex'] := tn.StateIndex;
  cNode.Attributes['selectedIndex'] := tn.SelectedIndex;

  //child nodes
  tn := tn.getFirstChild;
  while tn <> nil do
  begin
    ProcessTreeItem(tn, cNode);
    tn := tn.getNextSibling;
  end;
end; (*ProcessTreeItem*)

procedure XML2Form(tree : TJvPageListTreeView; XMLDoc : TXMLDocument);
var
  iNode : IXMLNode;
begin
  tree.Items.Clear;
  XMLDoc.FileName := ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0),'.XML');
  XMLDoc.Active := True;

  iNode := XMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First;

  while iNode <> nil do
  begin
    ProcessNode(iNode,nil);
    iNode := iNode.NextSibling;
  end;
  XMLDoc.Active := False;
end;

procedure Form2XML(tree: TJVPageListTreeView);
var
  tn : TTreeNode;
  XMLDoc : TXMLDocument;
  iNode : IXMLNode;
begin
  XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  XMLDoc.Active := True;
  iNode := XMLDoc.AddChild('tree2xml');
  iNode.Attributes['app'] := ParamStr(0);

  tn := tree.TopItem;
  while tn <> nil do
  begin
    ProcessTreeItem (tn, iNode);

    tn := tn.getNextSibling;
  end;

  XMLDoc.SaveToFile(ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0),'.XML'));
  XMLDoc := nil;
end; (* Form2XML *)
```

Comment: This question boils down to "Why is Pascal like pascal, and not like C?". :-) Nevertheless I am not voting to close as it's a legitimate new-user question.

Comment: Why would you declare variables in your procedure instead of making them global? I use this reasoning to sometimes use procedures in my procedures, to not have another global.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nested procedures like that do make sense in this XML related code. To process all nodes, a *recursive call* of `ProcessNode` is needed. You have to note that sometimes, inner functions need to access a lot more data than a few parameters.

Potential implementations may be:

- Use "flat" procedures, as in your implementation;
- Use "nested" procedures, as in the original implementation;
- Create a dedicated `class` (or `record` + methods) which will remain *private* to the `implementation` part of the unit.

Of course, the 3rd option sounds the more maintainable. It will allow clear separation of the process, *and* allow the use of variables local to their methods. Using a `record` (or an `object` for older versions of Delphi) will allow the processing object to be allocated on the stack of the main procedure, so you won't need to write `Obj := TInterType.Create; try .. finally Obj.Free`. But if you use an `object` please note that some new version of Delphi [has compilation issue](http://blog.synopse.info?post/2011/01/29/record-and-object-issue-in-Delphi-2010) - you should better use `record` with methods.

The "flat" procedure style is IMHO not better than "nested" procedure, and even worse, since it would need to add additional parameters to the inner calls, or use some global variables. By the way, having a lot of variables for every call will increase stack space, and reduce speed.

The "nested" style is in fact OOP oriented. When an inner function is called, the compiler pass the caller stack base in a register to the nested function (just like the additional `self` parameter of an object). So the inner function is able to access all the caller stack variables, just as if they were declared in a private object (the 3rd solution).

The Delphi IDE and internal debugger handles nested procedures quite well. IMHO it could make sense for some small piece of code (that is, something that can be read on the same screen height). Then, when you need more process, a dedicated `record/object` with methods and explicit variables will be more maintainable. But the "flat" option is IMHO not to be coded.

I've just [written a blog article about these implementation patterns](http://blog.synopse.info?post/2012/05/20/Recursive-calls-and-private-objects), which will present some source code of a *QuickSort* implementation, which will use as little stack space as possible, and will avoid a call to a nested procedure inside a procedure, and use a dedicated private `object` instead.

In all cases, do not be afraid of creating some internal objects/classes to implement your algorithms. The latest versions of Delphi allows even private types in `class` definition - but sometimes, I feel more comfortable with making the internal object totally private to the `implementation` part of the unit, i.e. non even appearing as private members of the `interface` part of the unit.

Classes are not only meant for publishing your process outside of the unit: OOP applies also to *implementation* patterns. Your code will be more maintainable, and in most case, the `self` parameter will be used to refer to all associated data at once, so your code may also be even faster and lighter!

Comment: the link to the blog above was not found - but I found it on the wayback archive

https://web.archive.org/web/20200128142046/http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/05/20/Recursive-calls-and-private-objects

Comment: I updated the link, sorry.

Answer (score 13):

Coding with inner procedures like that is a matter of style. One could argue that it's "cleaner"  ...in the same sense of encapsulating all the related data and routines inside *one* thingy as one hears about for "object-oriented programming" ...but it also has disadvantages: more difficult to code correctly initially, harder to test, harder for many programmers to understand (and thus possibly less maintainable).

Defining an inner procedure keeps future programmers from accidentally calling the inner procedure and expecting it to do something reasonable. That inner procedure isn't even defined -hence can't be called- at an outer/global level.

Defining an inner procedure also means less chance of a name collision in the outer/global namespace, since the inner routine doesn't contribute anything to that namespace. (This is an excellent example: how many different things all named "ProcessNode(...)" are likely?)

And as noted, in most languages the inner routine has "special" access to what would otherwise be invisible local data types and variables.

Answer (score 4):

There's one problem with your revised version: it references `tree`, which is a parameter to the main method.  That's one thing that can be accomplished with nested procedures: they can access any variable from outer scopes that's been declared so far.

Having said that, a lot of developers find nested procedures to be a messy coding style and prefer to avoid it; they'd generally rewrite it like you did, but add `tree` as another parameter to `ProcessNode`.

Comment: +1 I don't find nested procedures messy, unless they are long, a small recursive procedure is worth a trillion bux! (:

Comment: Some people like to hide things that shouldn't be callable outside the context they were designed to be used from.  This kind of "hiding" is not only found in objects (with private/protected) it's also a reason for nested procedures, and is the reason (structure programming) that Wirth put the feature into the language in the first place.  One can accomplish most of that purpose by making a non-local function that is only used and declared in the implementation section, and then, all you lose is the ability to share local scope.

Answer (score 3):

Nested procedures / functions have been available in Delphi long before OOP hast been added to it. That all happened around 25 years ago. Back in those times, local functions inside a function helped to keep to global scope cleaner and related code closer together.
Borland / Inprise / Embarcadero never dropped that feature, of course because otherwise they would have created a huge incompatibility. 
So use it if it makes sense to you, otherwise just let it be.

Comment: Please try to format an answer so that it becomes more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting procedures and functions ( see [Nested_function in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function) ) are used for information hiding and private sharing of local variables with the nested function.  See below quotes from the Wikipedia article.  The questioned code did not seem to use shared local variables, but seem to choose to pass them as parameters.  By nesting the procedure it communicates to the reader that on other outside code accesses the nested code. This is not clear from the "modified code"

> Lexically nested function definitions are a form of information hiding and are useful for dividing procedural tasks into subtasks which are only meaningful locally. This avoids cluttering other parts of the program with functions and variables that are unrelated to those parts.

> In languages with nested functions, functions may normally also contain local constants, and types (in addition to local variables, parameters, and functions), encapsulated and hidden in the same nested manner, at any level of depth. This may further enhance the code structuring possibilities.